# Copy then edit html page PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to copy an HTML file with a video player on it, then with my PHP form take the direct link input as a variable.

```
<source src="$link" type="video/mp4">
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
     <form method="POST" action="action.php">
     <p>Video Title</p>   <input type="text" name="title"> <br>
     <p>Video Link</p> <input type="text" name="link"> <br>
     <p>Description</p> <input type="text" name="desc"> <br>
     <p>Page Name</p>    <input type="text" name="pagename"> <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
  </body>
```

ACTION.PHP

```
<?php
   $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
 $link = htmlspecialchars($_POST['link']);
 $desc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['desc']);
$pgname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pagename']);


 copy('index.html', $pgname . '.html');

$myFile = $pgname . '.html';



   ?>
```

I don't know how to use the direct video link as a variable in the Html.

Comment: You mean you want to actually obtain the page off the internet and put it in a variable? If so, curl is probably what you're looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Duplicate a page within my own webhosting server

Answer (score 0):

So, if I get this right, you want to accept two post variables, one of which calls up the text of a page, and the second one is used in that page, and then it's written out to a file again? It sounds like you're doing a template system, and you might check out something built for that - like [Plates](http://platesphp.com/). But here is how to generally do it without Plates (untested):

```
$ch = curl_init($pgname);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$bodytag = str_replace("text_in_page_to_replace", $link, $output);

$fh = fopen("where_to_save.html", 'w');
fwrite($fh, $output);
fclose($fh);
```

You could use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), but I'm not sure if your files are on the same server or what your structure is. Either way, the same general idea would be the above.